# Find the voltage drop across the capacitor in the LRC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am having issues finding the voltage drop across this capacitor in the circuit attached.[image: A circuit consisting of a current source, resistor, inductor, and capacitor]

Attempt: The impedance of the inductor is 50j ohms, and the impedance of the capacitor is -j20 ohms. This means that the equivalent impedance is 100 +j30 ohms. To get the voltage, I multiply the current by this impedance. Doing this I get 1040 cos(1000t + 17degrees) V. Is this correct?

Comment: (10*50uF/(100+50mH+50uF)) is -0.550458716 - j1.83486239 or 1.91565257 < -106.699244

Answer (score 2):

You know the current through the capacitor, and the reactance of the capacitor, that’s all you need.

Comment: He means Vc(t)= 10cos(1000t) * (-j20) = I(t) * Zc

Comment: Wouldn't that make the voltage negative?

Comment: Voltage always lags the phase of current in a capacitor and this has a current source that is time variant so the voltage is AC alternating current and alternating voltage

Comment: if this were a voltage source then you must compute current using V(t)/( X(L) + R + X(C))=I(t) or convert to a vector with an angle, so in this case R and L have no effect on the current source amplitude in one loop and @jonk 's comment is incorrect